# Levenshtein Distance with Haskell Vectors and Memoization

Tags: haskell, memoization, levenshtein-distance

Is the following an effective way to implement the Levenshtein Distance with Haskell vectors?

```
  import qualified Data.Vector as V

  levenshtein s1 s2 = levenshteinV (V.fromList s1) (V.fromList s2)

  levenshteinV p1 p2 = lev V.! l1 V.! l2
    where
      lev    = V.map levi      (V.enumFromN 0 (l1 + 1))
      levi i = V.map (levij i) (V.enumFromN 0 (l2 + 1))
      levij i j
        | i == 0    = j
        | j == 0    = i
        | otherwise =
          ((lev V.! (i - 1) V.!  j)      + 1) `min`
          ((lev V.!  i      V.! (j - 1)) + 1) `min`
          ((lev V.! (i - 1) V.! (j - 1)) + ind (i - 1) (j - 1))

      ind i j = if p1 V.! i == p2 V.! j then 0 else 1
      l1      = V.length p1
      l2      = V.length p2
```

In particular, should I be using `V.map` to construct the vectors or is there a better approach? Perhaps `V.generate`? Or does it not make a difference because of lazy evaluation?

Answer (score 2):

Readability improves a lot with `import Data.Vector ((!))` and replacing `V.!` with `!`.

`generate` looks better; performance-wise I do not expect a difference (with optimization).

```
lev    = V.generate (l1 + 1) levi
```

If you like point-free notation, you can short-cut levi, with intermediate manual steps:

```
  lev    = V.generate (l1 + 1) levi
  levi i = V.generate (l2 + 1) (levij i)
```

2

```
  lev    = V.generate (l1 + 1) (\i ->
           V.generate (l2 + 1) (levij i))
```

3

```
  lev    = V.generate (l1 + 1) (\i -> V.generate (l2 + 1) (levij i))
```

4

```
  lev    = V.generate (l1 + 1) (V.generate (l2 + 1) . levij)
```

Your code looks good. You might try it with `Array` next, to two-dimensional Index. The google results for *haskell* *levenshtein* *Array* are only marginally better than your Vector approach.

Comment: Thanks. I also read about the `repa` library but it is bit mysterious to me. Would you be able to help me translate this to use repa? It could be a tutorial for me and also we can see whether it would perform better.